# Generating N variables in Python/Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to generate N variables in python : var1, var2,..., varN
I'm creating N Checkbuttons and I need variables for these.

My ultimate goal would be that when you tick in the checkbox an element in a list is saved and when it is unticked it is deleted.

I first tought of doing a list but in the checkbutton, "var[i]" is not recognized.

The following code doesn't work but here's the idea.

```
... # all the window setup
for i in range(N):
    save=Checkbutton(table,variable=var[i],command = lambda : saveinfile(i))
    save.grid(row=i+1,column=0)
```

Comment: Have you considered `vars.append(tk.StringVar())`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you haven't specified what's wrong. Do you get error messages? Are you unable to append to the list? Are you having trouble deleting the items from the list? Please explain the problem you are having. See [ask] for more information on asking a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the suggestion by @Bryan Oakley, here is a more verbose explanation:

With the `saveinfile()` function as result printout and N=3:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def saveinfile(i):
    print(f'Checkbutton {i} - {button_var_list[i].get()}')

button_var_list = []
for i in range(3):
    var = tk.StringVar()
    save = tk.Checkbutton(root, variable=var, command=lambda i=i: saveinfile(i))
    save.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
    button_var_list.append(var)

root.mainloop()
```

Note the lambda function `command=lambda i=i: saveinfile(i)` sets the variable `i` as a default variable, or all lambda functions would point to the last value of `i`, in my example = 2.